# how to get json data from a URL in laravel to android

Tags: php, android, json, laravel-5

I am trying to get data from a URL in my localhost to an android app, but I always get `FileNotFoundException` with this URL:

http://10.0.2.2/index.php/androidqname/PC396458

However, when I use another test json data online it works fine. For example, with this URL:
http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/otherkey/othervalue

This is my android code which I call inside a class that extends the asyntask

```
public String newServerRequest(String uri)
{

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    int resCode=0;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

        resCode=connection.getResponseCode();
        InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
            Log.d("Response Laminjanneh: ", "> " + line +" "+resCode);   //here u ll get whole response...... :-)

        }

        String finalObj=buffer.toString();

        JSONObject parentObj= new JSONObject(finalObj);

        //JSONArray jArray= parentObj.getJSONArray(0);

        String name = parentObj.getString("otherkey");
        String fname = parentObj.getString("key");



        return name+" == "+fname;


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Response janneh 1 : ", "> " + e.getMessage()+" "+resCode);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("Response janneh 2 : ", "> " + e.getMessage()+" "+resCode);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;

}
```

This is my laravel controller that is giving me the JSON data:

```
public function questionairename($pcodenumber)
{
    $questionaireName= Questionaire_name::where('project_code_number','=',$pcodenumber)->get();

     return json_encode($questionaireName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, your mobile device cannot connect to the server of your local machine. So that the server cannot be reached remotely you cannot do it. In this case you have to host your web app in such a server which can be accessed globally from the world.

Otherwise you can try connecting both devices (mobile and pc) in a same network.

Another recommendation though it's not related to the question, is to use any of the network libraries like `Volley` or `Retrofit` instead of `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using my emulator .

Comment: Try the url http://10.0.2.2/index.php/androidqname/PC396458 is accessible from the browser of the emulator or not.

Comment: This is the reason for what it's being failed to fetch json from your local server.

Comment: So the only way is however make your server accessible from your emulator or from real device.

Answer (score 0):

`10.0.2.2` is an alias for `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` for the **android emulator** only. If you want to access your server from a device running your app then:

1) Either your server needs to be publicly accessible or The device and server need to be in the same network

2) The server should be configure to accept connections from other devices in the network

Comment: I am getting the error when using the android emulator, thanks for the reply

Comment: Have you tested if it works from the browser on your machine? Just replace `10.0.2.2` with `localhost` for that. Also check if your server is running on some other port

Comment: No that  doesn't work for me. I got the message

This site can’t be reached

10.0.2.2 took too long to respond.

Comment: Yes it's still a local request. I mean that you navigate to `localhost/index.php/androidqname/PC396458` on a browser on the server to test if the server is working

Comment: yes with this localhost/index.php/androidqname/PC396458 is working 

but it does not work for 10.0.2.2/index.php/androidqname/PC396458

Comment: That won't work because as I said earlier its an alias for the android emulator only. Can you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: yes I understand that it is an alias. Infact I am getting response from the server it just that it returns 404 error  which is filenotFoundException. am I missing anything?